# How does "a great high priest" compare with "a royal priesthood"?

Tags: word-study, hebrews

> "Since then we have a great high priest who has passed through the heavens, Jesus, the Son of God, let us hold fast our confession." Hebrews 4:14  ESV.

> "But you are a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for his own possession, that you may proclaim the excellencies of him who called you out of darkness into his marvelous light." 1 Peter 2:9 ESV.

What similarities might Christ as "a great high priest" have with Christians described as "a royal priesthood"?

The words "priest" or "priesthood" come in these descriptions. How do they compare? [When the same, when different?]

Comment: Please clarify - Kohanim were sons of Aharon (Kohen Gadol) , as Xians are children of Jesus (High Priest) ?

Comment: What might Christians as beloning to a priesthood have in common with their high priest? Do they compare?

Comment: @חִידָה No, Christians are the adopted siblings of Jesus. Or his bride. There are multiple metaphors in the Bible. But as far as I know Jesus is never called our father.

Comment: Ignoring what tranx route the passages took, a priest is an individual person and a priesthood is an organisation. Either way, a "great high priest" could conceivably come from anywhere but a "royal (high) priest" only from the royal bloodline. How is what any priesthood might have in common with the high priest not covered there, please? What language are you reading or thinking in, that leaves doubts there?

Answer (score 1):

1 Peter 2:9 references a demographic "royal priesthood" representing a "holy nation" from **[Exodus 19:6]** "And you shall be to Me a **[kingdom of priests]** מַמְלֶ֥כֶת כֹּֽהֲנִ֖ים and a holy nation.' These are the words that you shall speak to the children of Israel." (וְאַתֶּ֧ם תִּֽהְיוּ־לִ֛י מַמְלֶ֥כֶת כֹּֽהֲנִ֖ים וְג֣וֹי קָד֑וֹשׁ אֵ֚לֶּה הַדְּבָרִ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר תְּדַבֵּ֖ר אֶל־בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל)

Ellicott Commentary on [1 Peter 2:9]

> A royal priesthood, an holy nation.—These words are a direct quotation from Exodus 19:6, according to the LXX. version. The Hebrew has “a kingdom of priests,” as in Revelation 1:6 (according to the best reading); which would mean, God’s organised empire, every member of which is a priest. Nor is the thought far different here. The word “royal” does not seem intended to imply that every Christian is a king, or of royal birth (though that, of course, may be shown from elsewhere), but describes his belonging to the King

**How do the Royal Priests [1 Peter 2:9] relate to their High Priest Jesus, the Son of God [Hebrews 4:14]?**

For Peter - Royal Priests compared to Jesus are like "Peacemakers" (εἰρηνοποιοί) belonging to the King as His "children" (υἱοὶ, masculine pl.) stated in Matthew 5:9.

For Paul - Faith πίστεως would make Royal Priests υἱοί Ἀβραάμ "son(s) of Abraham" [Galatians 3:7] similar to Jesus [Matthew 1:1] since The Descendants of Avram in [Psalm 110:4] are considered priests forever, עַל־דִּ֜בְרָתִ֗י מַלְכִּי־צֶֽדֶק "because of the speech of Malchizedek".

Comment: Peacemakers and children+1. And relationship to Melchizedek?

Comment: What relationship to מַלְכִּי צֶֽדֶק Malki Tzedek? The Descendants of Avram in [Psalm 110:4] are considered priests forever, עַל־דִּ֜בְרָתִ֗י מַלְכִּי־צֶֽדֶק "because of the speech of Malchizedek".

Comment: Are the spiritual descendants of Abraham of the 'order of Melchizedek?

Comment: For Paul - Faith πίστεως would make Royal Priests υἱοί Ἀβραάμ "son(s) of Abraham" [Galatians 3:7] similar to Jesus [Matthew 1:1] since The Descendants of Avram in [Psalm 110:4] are considered priests forever, עַל־דִּ֜בְרָתִ֗י מַלְכִּי־צֶֽדֶק "because of the speech of Malchizedek".

Answer (score 1):

The words "priest" or "priesthood" come in these descriptions. How do they compare?

Hebrews 4:

> 14 Since then we have a great **high priest** who has passed through the heavens, Jesus, the **Son** of God, let us hold fast our confession.

high priest
ἀρχιερέα (archierea)
Noun - Accusative Masculine Singular
Strong's 749: High priest, chief priest. From arche and hiereus; the high-priest; by extension a chief priest.

High-priest is one Greek word.
In the context of Hebrews, it refers to the Son.

1 Peter 2:

> 9 But **you** are a chosen race, a royal **priesthood**, a holy nation, a people for his own possession, that you may proclaim the excellencies of him who called you out of darkness into his marvelous light.

*Priesthood* refers to not one person but a collection of priests (not high-priest).
Peter was talking about fellow believers.
High-priest and priesthood in these contexts are different concepts.

What similarities might Christ as "a great high priest" have with Christians described as "a royal priesthood"?

The answer is found in
Hebrews 2:

> 17 Therefore he had to be made like his brothers in every respect, so that he might become a merciful and faithful high priest in the service of God, to make propitiation for the sins of the people. 18For because he himself has suffered when tempted, he is able to help those who are being tempted.

The great high-priest Christ became a human like his human brothers in order to form a royal priesthood of chosen people to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

These metaphors of Jesus all fall into a series forming a consistent pattern as follows:

- Jesus is our Great **High Priest** (ἀρχιερεύς = leading priest, Heb 4:14, 8:1, etc) who is head/leader of the royal priesthood (ἱεράτευμα, 1 Peter 2:5, 9), the church of Jesus Christ who are thus denoted as "priests" (ἱερεύς, hiereus)
- Jesus is our **King** (Luke 1:33, John 1:49, Acts 13:23, Rev 11:15) of the Holy nation (1 Peter 2:5, 9), His church
- Jesus the **Great Shepherd** (ἀρχιποίμην, 1 Peter 5:4, see also John 10:11, 14) and we are the sheep of His pasture (John 10:4, 27, 1 Peter 2:25, etc), His church
- Jesus is the great **Overseer** (1 Peter 2:25) of us all, His church
- Jesus is our great **Example** (John 13:15, 1 Peter 2:21, 1 Tim 1:16) that we follow ("Christians" are those who are like Christ) to create His church
- Jesus is the **chief cornerstone or “capstone”** (Eph 2:19-22, 1 Peter 2:4-8, Acts 4:11, Matt 21:42, Mark 12:10, Luke 20:17) with the members of the Christian community are bricks in the temple of God (1 Cor 3:16, 17)
- Jesus set an example of how to **love** (John 13:34, 35, 1 John 4:8, 16) that we should love as He loves us

**Priesthood**

There are actually three words translated "priesthood:

- ἱερωσύνη (hierósuné, feminine) which occurs only in Heb 7:11, 12, 24 and denotes the office of the priest
- ἱερατεία (hierateia, feminine) which occurs only in Luke 1:9, Heb 7:5 and denotes  the priest service
- ἱεράτευμα (hierateuma, neuter) which occurs only in 1 Peter 2:5, 9 and denotes an order of holy priests

In any case, Jesus is the head of the of the priesthood and the great high priest.

Answer (score 1):

#### How does "a great high priest" compare with "a royal priesthood"?

Under the Mosiac Law, the high priest was the only one allowed to make atonement for the nation of Israel.

> The high priest alone was to go into the Most Holy compartment of the sanctuary, and only on one day of the year, the Day of Atonement. (Le 16:2) When he went into the tent of meeting on that day, no other priest was allowed in the tent. (Le 16:17) He officiated over all the Atonement Day services.–("[High Priest](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002023#h=20)" from *Insight on the Scriptures*)

Jesus Christ, upon his ascension back to heaven, makes atonement for sinful mankind. ([Hebrews 9:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/73/1)) He is the only one that could make this atonement. ([Romans 5:19](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/45/5#study=discover&v=45:5:19))

Under the Mosiac Law, the priesthood was made up of only Levites (Kohathites) that were Aaron's sons.

> The appointment of a priest must come from God; a man does not take the office of his own accord. (Heb 5:4) Accordingly, Jehovah himself appointed Aaron and his house to the priesthood “to time indefinite,” separating them from the family of the Kohathites, one of the three main divisions of the tribe of Levi. (Ex 6:16; 28:43)-("[Priest](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200003553?q=priesthood&p=sen#h=9)" from *Insight on the Scriptures*)

The priesthood's duties were in all things having to do with the sacrifices, maintaining the tabernacle or temple, and teaching the people the Law.

As to the "royal priesthood", Peter explains their duties:

> you yourselves like living stones are being built up as a spiritual house, to be a holy priesthood, **to offer spiritual sacrifices acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.**–[1 Peter 2:5 ESV](https://biblehub.com/esv/1_peter/2.htm)

So those of the priesthood help Jesus Christ as the high priest. They are a **royal** priesthood because they are under their king Jesus Christ. Just as Melchizedek, Jesus is a king and high priest. ([Heb 5:5, 6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200000285/33/3))

So the "great high priest" and "royal priesthood" are related but not the same.

[Unless otherwise noted, all scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Comment: "offer spiritual sacrifices"+1. e.g. Hebrews 13:15, Romans12:1 any others?

Comment: @C.Stroud yes, those two scriptures are applicable here. I couldn't find any others right now but will do more research for you.